# Windows 7: How to make active window much visible at taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, themes

Win 7 is fancy but XP was much better at accessibility... I can't recognize easily which window is active at taskbar, active item has an extra "glow". Is there any way to improve that?

Comment: i would also love to solve this!

Comment: You can disable the Themes service in services.msc which noticeably makes it easier to see which window is open. You can also right-click the taskbar, go to properties and set the View Mode to Never Combine rather than Always combine. This will look very similar to how the taskbar looked in XP